# In flask_uploads , we can import IMAGES so is there anything like 'DOCUMENTS' to import docs like pdf, docs etc etc...?

Tags: python, flask, flask-uploads

Actually I want to open pdf file but dont know how to open in flask I mean we have 'IMAGES' for images. So is there anything for pdf? or we can directly import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend to use `Flask-Reuploaded` instead of `Flask-Uploads` as the latter is not longer properly maintained.

You can find more about `Flask-Reuploaded` at its GitHub repository:

https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded

There are different sets of files, including `DOCUMENTS`, which includes `pdf`, `doc`, `docx` and many more, which you can look up in the documentation:

https://flask-reuploaded.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_uploads.DOCUMENTS